# Wrapping around the edges in a 2d array (game of life)?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, conways-game-of-life

I'm having trouble figuring out how to handle wrapping the edge cases of a 2d array back around, so that a number out of bounds will wrap around to the opposite edge of the grid.

This is my current code, it works somewhat but I have noticed that it isn't actually properly wrapping around the grid.

```
wrap: function (x, min, max){ 
    if (x < min) {
        return max + x
    } 
    else if (x === min) {
        return max - 10
    }
    else if (x > max) {
        return min + 10
    } else if (x <= max){
        return max % x 
    }
    // return x < 0 ? max + x : min
},



get_neighbour:function(x, y) {
    if (g.grid[x] && g.grid[x][y]){
        return g.grid[x][y].state
    } else {
        (g.grid[x]) ? x = x : x = g.func.wrap(x, 0, 500) ;
        (g.grid[y]) ? y = y : y = g.func.wrap(y, 0, 500) ;
        return g.grid[x][y].state
    }
},
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is the constant `10` coming from?

Comment: If it wasn't for that weird 10, wrap could probably be `return ((x-min) % (max-min)) + min` — which gets even simpler if you let `min` always be 0.

Comment: The 10 is the grid size or cell width. I'll be changing it to be in relation to the cell size later, but for now it's easier for me to think in constants.

as in the 10 will be changed to cell.width later on, if that's clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `wrap` function is incomplete.  It handles the case when `x` is less than 0, but when `x` is not less than 0, it always returns `min`.  At that point, there are two cases: `x` is less than or equal to `max`, or `x` is greater than `max`, and you'd need to handle them.  It might make it simpler if you use `if` and `else if` than the `?:` operator — the code will definitely be more readable, and mistakes will be easier to spot.

(Besides, in the code above `min` is always 0, but in principle you should check whether `x` is less than `min` instead of 0.)

Comment: Thank you - that really helped me see where I was going wrong. I've updated the OP with my now functioning wraparound code.